# Localhost cannot handle request PDO register user

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i was trying to make from scratch a PDO, OOP user/register system in PHP and i got stucked in the point where I don't understand why I it's trowing me the handle request error.

This is my index.php file with login and register:

```
<?php
  require_once('inc/config.php');

  if($user->is_loggedIn()!="") {
    $user->redirect('account.php');
  }

  // login
  if(isset($_POST['login-submit'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($user->login($username, $password)) {
      $user->redirect('account.php');
    }
    else {
      $error[] = "Username or Password are not correct!";
    }
  }

  //register
  if(isset($_POST['register-submit'])) {
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    if($username == "") {
      $error[] = "You need to specify a username!";
    }
    else if($password == "") {
      $error[] = "Please add a password!";
    }
    else if(strlen($password) < 6) {
      $error[] = "Password must have at least 6 characters";
    }
    else {
      try {
        $stmt = $db_connection->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:user_name");
        $stmt->bindParam(':user_name', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        // execute(array(':user_name'=>$username));
        $row->$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($row['username'] == $username) {
          $error[] = "Sorry, this username is already taken!";
        }
        else {
          if($user->register($username, $password)) {
            $user->redirect('index.php?success');
          }
        }
      }
      catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
      }
    }
  }



?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Login/Register</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="panel panel-login">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <a href="#" class="active" id="login-form-link">Login</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <a href="#" id="register-form-link">Register</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
              <?php
                if(isset($error)) {
                  foreach($error as $error) {
              ?>
                  <div class="alert alert-danger">
                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> &nbsp; <?php echo $error; ?>
                  </div>
              <?php
                  // end for each
                  }
                // end of if statement
                } else if(isset($_GET['success'])) { ?>
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i> &nbsp; Successfully registered! You can now log in!
                </div>
              <?php } ?>
                <form id="login-form" action="#" method="post" role="form" style="display: block;">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group text-center">

                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Log In">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="text-center">

                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
                <form id="register-form" action="#" method="post" role="form" style="display: none;">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Register Now">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tabs.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my config.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

//set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Copenhagen');

//database credentials
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','admin');
define('DBPASS','Ddy6MUXhtUz3mNpE');
define('DBNAME','notes_app');

//application address
define("BASE_URL","/");
define("ROOT_PATH",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/");

try {
    $db_connection = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $db_connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "Connection failed " . $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

include_once('models/user.php');
$user = new User($db_connection);
```

And this is my user model:

```
<?php

class User {
    private $db;

    function __construct($db_connection) {
        $this->db = $db_connection;
    }

    public function register($username, $password) {
        try {
            $crypted_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES(:user_name, :user_pass)");

            $stmt->execute(array(":user_name"=>$username, ":user_pass"=>$crypted_password));

            return $stmt;
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function login($username, $password) {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:user_name");
            $stmt->bindParam(':user_name', $username);
            $stmt->execute();
            $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                if(password_verify($username, $userRow['password'])) {
                    $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['id'];
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function is_loggedIn() {
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_session'])) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function redirect($url) {
        header("Location: $url");
    }

    public function logout() {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['user_session']);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I was trying for several hours to find the problem but unfortunately I couldn't find it, I cannot neither print the var_dump because my browser is receiving the internal error 500.

Comment: Post the relevant code on SO, not on external websites.

Comment: What is the error you get in the logs?

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Have you checked your logs?

Comment: **why did you went and put up links that expire?? why??** in 29 days, your question will be useless to all. I for one won't be offering help here. Good luck

Comment: Are you serious you are developing with the error reporting disabled? Programming is a science, but what you're doing is just a guessing or fortune-telling-like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because of the following lines:

- In your `login()` method of `User` class,

  ```
  if(password_verify($username, $userRow['password'])) { ...
  ```
- And on **index.php** page, during the processing of registration form,

  ```
  $row->$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  ```

So your `login()` method should be like this:

```
public function login($username, $password) {
    try {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:user_name");
        $stmt->bindParam(':user_name', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            if(password_verify($password, $userRow['password'])) {
                $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['id'];
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

And change this line

```
$row->$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

to

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: I wouldn't have posted an answer for expiring pastebin links.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The links haven't expired, it's working on my end. I've edited the question.

Comment: all links pastebin links are set to be deleted *in 29 days*. Look for yourself.

Comment: @Fred-ii- oops, my apologies, I didn't know that. Anyways, I've updated the question, now I guess this question makes more sense. :-)

Comment: You're a good soul Rajdeep, however it isn't our job nor should it be to fetch code and especially when they expire. The OP should have known better. Oh and it's not for you to apologize here ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-  I'm sorry, tought that it will be easy to read the code from pastebin, I didn't checked if it will expire but I'll know it in the future!